# sql group by order by and top in a same query

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables `Company`, `Designation` and `Employee`.

I need a query to select the top 2 employee from all the designation grouped by company have tried something and attached my screenshot here, please help me with a query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company](
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Company Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Designation](
    [Design ID] [int] NULL,
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Emp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Design ID] [int] NULL,
    [Employee Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Company] ([Comp ID], [Company Name]) VALUES (1, N'Company 1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Company] ([Comp ID], [Company Name]) VALUES (2, N'Company 2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation]) VALUES (1, 1, N'CEO')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation]) VALUES (2, 1, N'HR')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation]) VALUES (3, 2, N'CEO')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Developer')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'Test emp1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, N'Test emp2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (3, 1, 2, N'Test emp3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (4, 1, 2, N'Test emp4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (5, 1, 1, N'Test emp5')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (6, 1, 2, N'Test emp6')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (7, 2, 1, N'Test emp7')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (8, 2, 1, N'Test emp8')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (9, 2, 2, N'Test emp9')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (10, 2, 2, N'Test emp10')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (11, 2, 1, N'Test emp11')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (12, 2, 1, N'Test emp12')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (13, 1, 1, N'Test emp13')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (14, 1, 2, N'Test emp14')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (15, 2, 1, N'Test emp15')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (16, 2, 2, N'Test emp16')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (17, 1, 1, N'Test emp17')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (18, 1, 2, N'Test emp18')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (19, 2, 1, N'Test emp19')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name]) VALUES (20, 2, 2, N'Test emp20')
GO
```

and the query i have tried is,

```
select 
emp.[Emp ID],
comp.[Company Name],
design.[Designation],
emp.[comp id],
emp.[Employee Name]
from employee as emp
join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]

order by emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc
```

Comment: Top 2 employees with regard to _what_?  Which column do you want to use for ordering employees with a company/designation?

Comment: Top two employee by *what* criteria? Also, we don't need typing/transcription practice - your samples would be better presented as *text* (ideally as `CREATE TABLE` and a *small* set of sample data `INSERT` statements) rather than pictures.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: select 
emp.[Emp ID],
comp.[Company Name],
design.[Designation],
emp.[comp id],
emp.[Employee Name]
from employee as emp
join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]

order by emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc

My query i need top 2 employees by employee id

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Do not post code in comments. [edit] your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) inside of a subquery to select the top 2 rows returned per company and designation.

```
SELECT
    [Company Name],
    [Designation],
    [comp id],
    [Employee Name]
FROM
(
    SELECT emp.[Emp ID],
        comp.[Company Name],
        design.[Designation],
        emp.[comp id],
        emp.[Employee Name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.[Comp ID], emp.[Design ID] ORDER BY emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc) RowNum
    from employee as emp
        join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
        join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]
) a
WHERE RowNum <=2
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
The multi-part identifier "comp.Company Name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
The multi-part identifier "design.Designation" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
The multi-part identifier "emp.comp id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
The multi-part identifier "emp.Employee Name" could not be bound.

Comment: Fixed. I had copied the column names from below and forgotten to remove the prefix.

Comment: thanks , i need additional requirement like, from my three of the table i need first 4 employees from each company ordered by Designation ID then By Employee ID

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE you can achieve desire result

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    select emp.[Emp ID], 
           comp.[Company Name], 
           design.[Designation], 
           emp.[comp id], 
           emp.[Employee Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp.[comp id],design.[Designation] ORDER BY design.[Design ID],emp.[Emp ID])   RN
   from employee as emp 
   join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID] 
   join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID] 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN <= 4
```

Comment: Whenever the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` column sets are identical, you're effectively saying "I don't care". I'm sure the OP does care, they've just not done a good job of explaining it yet.

Comment: it returns same rows as my query i need top two employees from each catagory per company

Comment: Damien,
my question is i have three tables as Company, Designation, Employee
i need a query which will select top 2 employees ( by employee ID ) from each designation for both the companies

Comment: thanks Jaydip,
i need additional requirement like, from my three of the table i need first 4 employees from each company ordered by Designation ID then By Employee ID

Comment: Updated as per new request, try it

Comment: thanks but i have asked to group the employees by company and order by designation id and employee id which means top 4 employees per company not by designation