# sql pivot with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: Expected Result will be like]i have already posted my question in the link [sql group by order by and top in a same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340791/sql-group-by-order-by-and-top-in-a-same-query) the result for my request is,

```
SELECT
    [Company Name],
    [Designation],
    [comp id],
    [Employee Name]
FROM
(
    SELECT emp.[Emp ID],
        comp.[Company Name],
        design.[Designation],
        emp.[comp id],
        emp.[Employee Name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.[Comp ID], emp.[Design ID] ORDER BY emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc) RowNum
    from employee as emp
        join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
        join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]
) a
WHERE RowNum <=2
```

can anyone help me to pivot this query, thanks in advance

Comment: can u show expected output ................

Comment: Based on the company Name i need to pivot,
so the columns will be like Company Name, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4

Comment: How do you know which employee is emp1, which is emp2... ?

Comment: each and every company is going to have maximum of 4 employees so first record is going to be Emp1, and second will be 2 like wise..., is it possible with alias name

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible with alias name"?

Comment: to add alias name for the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a set number of employess in your list (from your comment) you don't need it to be dynamic. A regular pivot should do the trick:

```
select [Company Name],Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4  from (
    SELECT
        [Company Name],
        [Employee Name],
        'Emp' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Comp ID] ORDER BY  [Design ID], [Emp ID] desc) as char(2)) as RowNum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT emp.[Emp ID],
            comp.[Company Name],
            design.[Designation],
            emp.[Design ID],
            emp.[comp id],
            emp.[Employee Name],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.[Comp ID], emp.[Design ID] ORDER BY emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc) RowNum
        from employee as emp
            join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
            join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]
    ) a
    WHERE RowNum <=2
) as pivotdata
pivot (max([Employee Name]) for [RowNum] in (Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4)) as P
```

Comment: uh thank you this is what i was expecting, but it shows the employees in different order than it has to be if you see the attached screenshot above

Comment: Ooops - I have a desc where there shouldn't be. I'll just edit that out...