# sql query for sort by with multiple tables and PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[sql pivot with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343598/sql-pivot-with-dynamic-columns) i have attached my query for tables and data here,

```
     /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Company]    Script Date: 13/04/2017 3:37:15 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company](
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Company Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Designation]    Script Date: 13/04/2017 3:37:15 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Designation](
    [Design ID] [int] NULL,
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Design Code] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 13/04/2017 3:37:15 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Emp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Comp ID] [int] NULL,
    [Design ID] [int] NULL,
    [Employee Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Employee Code] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Company] ([Comp ID], [Company Name]) VALUES (1, N'Company 1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Company] ([Comp ID], [Company Name]) VALUES (2, N'Company 2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation], [Design Code]) VALUES (1, 1, N'CEO', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation], [Design Code]) VALUES (2, 1, N'HR', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation], [Design Code]) VALUES (3, 2, N'CEO', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Designation] ([Design ID], [Comp ID], [Designation], [Design Code]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Developer', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'Test emp1', 101)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, N'Test emp2', 102)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (3, 1, 2, N'Test emp3', 103)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (4, 1, 2, N'Test emp4', 104)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (5, 1, 1, N'Test emp5', 105)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (6, 1, 2, N'Test emp6', 106)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (7, 2, 1, N'Test emp7', 107)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (8, 2, 1, N'Test emp8', 108)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (9, 2, 2, N'Test emp9', 109)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (10, 2, 2, N'Test emp10', 110)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (11, 2, 1, N'Test emp11', 111)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (12, 2, 1, N'Test emp12', 112)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (13, 1, 1, N'Test emp13', 113)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (14, 1, 2, N'Test emp14', 114)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (15, 2, 1, N'Test emp15', 115)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (16, 2, 2, N'Test emp16', 116)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (17, 1, 1, N'Test emp17', 117)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (18, 1, 2, N'Test emp18', 118)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (19, 2, 1, N'Test emp19', 119)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Emp ID], [Comp ID], [Design ID], [Employee Name], [Employee Code]) VALUES (20, 2, 2, N'Test emp20', 120)
GO
```

i have 3 tables as Company, Designation, Employee

i require a query to select latest 4 employees ( sort by Employee Code ) for Latest Designation ( Design Code ) for all the companies order by descending of Design Code then by descending of Employee Code and select top 4 records for each company
and the result needs to be Pivoted like

Ex:

```
CompanyID    Emp1     Emp2     Emp3     Emp4
----------
1            118      114      106      103
```

i have tried something like,

```
select       
  emp.[Comp ID],
  emp.[Design ID],
  emp.[Emp ID],
  emp.[Employee Code],
  design.[Design Code],
  emp.[Employee Code],
  comp.[Company Name],
  design.Designation,
  emp.[Employee Name]
  from Employee emp    
  join Designation design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
  join Company comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]
  order by comp.[Comp ID] desc, design.[Design Code] desc, emp.[Employee Code] desc
```

i need first 4 employees pivoted as emp1, emp2, emp3 and emp4 for each and every company it is possible that 2 might fall in one designation and 3 from other and same employee code can repeat with different company code, it need to be sorted by company code then by employee code

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Is this a *homework question*? SO is not a *do my work for me* platform...

Comment: updated my question, please refer the attached link i need similar query but to be sorted by Design Code then Employee Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for,

```
SELECT [comp id], 
       emp1, 
       emp2, 
       emp3, 
       emp4 
FROM   (SELECT [comp id], 
               [employee code], 
               'Emp' + Cast(rn AS CHAR(10)) AS Empname 
        FROM   (SELECT A.[comp id], 
                       A.[employee code], 
                       Row_number() 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY A.[comp id] 
                           ORDER BY B.[comp id], C.[design code] 
                         DESC, A.[employee code] DESC) 
                               AS rn 
                FROM   dbo.employee A 
                       INNER JOIN dbo.company B 
                               ON A.[comp id] = B.[comp id] 
                       INNER JOIN dbo.designation C 
                               ON C.[design code] = A.[design id] 
                                  AND C.[comp id] = B.[comp id])A 
        WHERE  rn <= 4)B 
       PIVOT ( Max([employee code]) 
             FOR empname IN (emp1, 
                             emp2, 
                             emp3, 
                             emp4) ) pv
```

Result looks like as below,

```
comp id    emp1 emp2 emp3 emp4
1          118  114  106  104
2          120  116  110  109
```

Note : As per my understanding

Comment: Invalid object name '#employee'.

Comment: I used temporary tables,replace with you actual table. (Remove #).
I have edited now.

Comment: ha thank you so much this is what i was asked for, can you please help me to convert this query as a sql function

Comment: @VickySelvam, If you do not need pre-compiled parameters, just put `CREATE VIEW dbo.MySupiDupiView AS SELECT...` in front and use it like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MySupiDupiView` or in joins like any table source...

Comment: @Shnugo can you please help me to make a function from the query

Comment: @VickySelvam it should suffice to write `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT ....`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        comp.[Company Name],
        design.[Designation],
        emp.[comp id],
        emp.[Employee Code],
        'Emp' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.[Comp ID], emp.[Design ID] ORDER BY emp.[Comp ID] desc, emp.[Design ID] desc, emp.[Emp ID] desc) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ColumnName
    from employee as emp
        join designation as design on design.[Design ID]=emp.[Design ID]
        join company as comp on comp.[Comp ID]=emp.[Comp ID]
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Employee Code]) FOR ColumnName IN(Emp1,Emp2,Emp3,Emp4)
) AS p
```

Comment: i need latest 4 employees for a company ordered by designation code ( latest ) may be two employees from one designation and 2 from other but employee code can repeat thats why i am requesting to sort by design code then by employee code,

updated my question with a query i have tried i need top 4 employees for each employees from my query and they need to be pivoted

Comment: @VickySelvam Sorry, I do not quite understand your logic... Please try to explain in other words, why for compID=1 The number 117 does not follow 118 and why 113,105 and 104 are ommitted. Without 104 one could think: *You want no CEOs, the rest should be HR*, but I cannot follow...

Comment: will explain clearly,

i have 3 tables as company, designation, employees
company contains designation and designation contains employees
so need a query to select latest 4 employees pivoted as emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4 and they are to be from latest Designation like HR is the latest Designation it may contain 1 employee and CEO is older than HR ( by Designation code ) might contain 10 employees so i need all the employees from HR and latest 3 employees ( by Employee Code ) from CEO

Comment: @VickySelvam What does *later*  or *older* mean?